# move fields in the user profile form in fieldsets

Tags: 7, forms, users

I want to move the email address fields in the user profile form (user/1/edit) in a custom fieldset. I have this code:

```
$form['change_mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => 'change email address cake',
    '#weight' => 6,
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
    '#tree' => FALSE,
);

$form['change_mail']['mail'] = $form['account']['mail'];
unset($form['account']['mail']);
$form['change_mail']['confirm_mail'] = $form['account']['confirm_mail'];
unset($form['account']['confirm_mail']);
```

But I get an error when I try to change my email address: `undefined index 'mail' in user_account_form_validate() (line 1232 of /modules/user/user.module).` Apparently, I can't 'unset' the fields. But I don't know how to get rid of them.

Comment: try setting $form['change_mail']['#tree'] = false. Some info here http://drupal.org/node/48643

Comment: isn't that what my code did? `$form['change_mail'] = array( ... '#tree' => FALSE,);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned the problem appears in `user_account_form_validate()` because you changed the `account` index from `$form['account']['mail']` to `$form['change_mail']['mail']`

the issue is with this line `form_set_value($form['account']['mail'], $mail, $form_state);`

In order to achieve what you are looking for you need to replace existing form validation with a custom validation as the following code:

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['change_mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => 'change email address cake',
    '#weight' => 6,
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
    '#tree' => FALSE,
  );

  $form['change_mail']['mail'] = $form['account']['mail'];
  unset($form['account']['mail']);
  $form['change_mail']['confirm_mail'] = $form['account']['confirm_mail'];
  unset($form['account']['confirm_mail']);


  $form['#validate'][0] = 'MODULE_NAME_user_account_form_validate';
}


function MODULE_NAME_user_account_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['account']['mail'] = $form['change_mail']['mail'];
  // original validation function
  user_account_form_validate($form, $form_state);
}
```

Comment: Why do you put `$form['#validate'][0] = 'MODULE_NAME_user_account_form_validate';` if you're adding a validation function? Isn't it supposed to be `$form['#validate'][] = 'MODULE_NAME_user_account_form_validate';`

Comment: I'm not adding validation, I'm replacing existing validation.

Comment: Oh, is it because we don't want to call `user_account_form_validate()` (which is index 0 in the #validate array) without changing the values first? I get it now. Thanks

Comment: exactly, I also changed the text in my answer.